# Conversion to dict from a list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

My list `idf_val` is a list of tuples which has `(some_value, word)` format. Its length is 2886 entries.

Here is the snippet:

[image]

Please see that the last element in my list is `(6.922, zombie)`.

When I try to convert this list into a dictionary, some how the length of my dictionary is only 39! Some how, its avoiding the keys which are represented by a same number.

Here is the screenshot of the result:

[image]

Can you please tell how I can map the whole list into a dictionary with all the elements?

Comment: That's expected because the indices are colliding with other elements in the list. Do you need 1-1 representation? You may need to restructure the output dictionary into something like this:

`{ 123: ['would', 'way'], 1234: ['not', 'one', 'zombiez'] }`

So you can have multiple words mapped to the same number.

Comment: No man. I need a only a single value corresponding to one key!.. I have found some other way to my solution but would just like to know if its possible. :)

Comment: I assume the words are unique, not the values. You should map it to a dictionary where the words are the keys. If you don't, you can avoid overlap when you two words share the same value. For example "youthful" and "zombies" have the same value to your current precision, so if you use value as the key these would overlap.